# Call super super class onResume() and onCreae()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two fragments A and B. B extends fragment A, so that

```
public class A extends Fragment{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //other stuff
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        someFunctionOnlyUsefulInFragmentA()
    }
}
```

And for the second class:

```
public class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //other stuff
    }
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        //Problem! I don't want to call function "someFunctionOnlyUsefulInFragmentA()"
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't want to execute all the code in fragment A's `onResume()` and `onCreate()` method, but some custom code, which is only used in fragment B. But android forces me to call `super.onCreate()` and `super.onResume()`.

What can I do in order to execute some custom code in fragment B's `onCreate()` or `onResume()` method without calling the ones in fragment A?

Do I need to change my whole code design? If so, how?

Comment: Then simply don't place the code in onResume of fragment A

Comment: You do not have to call `super.onCreate()` and `super.onResume()`. What do you mean by "Android forces you"?

Comment: Well, I do need some code executed in fragment A's onResume() method! My app crashes, if i don't include the super calls.

Comment: `if instanceof A { call method } else { do not }`

Comment: @TimCastelijns,  can you elaborate on where you would put that code? And how would you check the instance?

Comment: Scratch that suggestion, you have a design problem :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is related to inheritance rather than Android fragments. What you need to do is to rethink classes design, for example - instead of deriving Class `B` from Class `A`, introduce Class `BaseFragment` that both have `A` and `B` derive from (and share some functionality), and put `someFunctionOnlyUsefulInFragmentA()` only in `A` fragment. What you tried to do above is obvious violation of [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)).

Comment: well +1 for Liskov Substitution Principle

Answer (score 0):

You have some couple of things you can do:

1. Don't make class B extend class A, make it extend `Fragment`
2. Do some stuff to revert the effects of `someFunctionOnlyUsefulInFragmentA()` inside class B's `onResume()`
3. Don't put `someFunctionOnlyUsefulInFragmentA()` inside `onResume()` of class A, or put a condition before it to prevent calling that fuction in some cases

Comment: option 2 would be really dumb (no offense)

Comment: You don't know what it does, maybe it does something really useless that you can revert it easily.

Comment: It doesn't matter what it does, it's the concept that is dumb

Comment: Yeah, the question is not dumb at all. The guy wants to create a class that does not do what its parent does. This is quite understandable when you think of the concept of inheritance. Right?